# Saving into a database versus saving into a file?

Tags: silverlight, save

I have a Silverlight application and it will be able to update documents and save it, but which approach is better?

1. Save files against a database, such as blob field into a table

   OR
2. Save against a folder structure with a table about where the files are saved into the disk

   OR
3. Something else?

what about IsolatedStorage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving into disk is better if you don't change the locations of the file frequently. Storing everything into database as blob will increase the size of your database rapidly which reduces the performance of the system. Moreover if you select lot of blob objects from the database at the same time then it will consume lot of memory and reduce performance.